# (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: php, mysqli, wamp

I haven't found any solution yet

I am using wamp server, I don't think the problem is with my code but here is my code anyways.

this is my code:

```
<?php
   $conn = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
?>
```

I have another code that defines the server user pass and name which is

```
<?php
   define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
   define("DB_USER", "root");
   define("DB_PASS", "password");
   define("DB_NAME", "OPAC");
?>
```

Comment: Check `MySQL` is turned on. Are you getting green Wamp icon in Task Bar ?

Comment: I do get a green wamp Icon